# Connecting MongoDB Compass to WSL2 Mongo server

Tags: mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running a mongoDB server on Ubuntu via Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. (Windows build is 19041.) I have MongoDB Compass running on Windows, and it is happy to connect to my Mongo server in Windows, but I can't figure out how to give it access to the server in the subsystem. How can I accomplish this?